# How to install Slack on Ubuntu?

Tags: downloads, slack

I am trying to install on my ubuntu OS but unable to do so. I have downloaded the latest version. I can't simple find the setup file to install it in the system?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should find it where you told the browser to save it, the default being the Downloads folders (or equivalent in your language if not English).

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re running (1) the location where you downloaded the file from? With this it may be possible to offer an answer. Alternatively, you could install the Snap like this: `sudo snap install slack --classic`

Comment: I provided a short answer on how to install slack using [snap](https://snapcraft.io/store) [Installing slack on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1394063/1072779) Hope this help